# no_proxy node configuration is not working while running junkins job

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm

I am getting below error while deploying my project

```
 + npm install -g @angular/cli
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network request to https://nexus.in.abc.com/repository/npmregistry/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

Bypass the proxy configuration using the below command in jenkins script

```
 npm config set no_proxy https://nexus.in.abc.com
```

Please help.